# grails hibernate 3/4 in a plugin used in 3/4 apps

Tags: grails

I am trying to get a plugin to work in both 2.3 + 2.4 apps:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist

```
compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.6", {
 //compile ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4", {
 export = false
}
```

With the commented out 4.3.5.4 - the app works fine on grails 2.4 app but on 2.3 it reports back :

```
014-08-13 14:36:06,809 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: org/hibernate/event/spi/PreLoadEventListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/spi/PreLoadEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at grails.plugin.hibernate4.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure1.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:94)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:754)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.event.spi.PreLoadEventListener
    ... 11 more
2014-08-13 14:36:06,811 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: org/hibernate/event/spi/PreLoadEventListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/spi/PreLoadEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at grails.plugin.hibernate4.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure1.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:94)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:754)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.event.spi.PreLoadEventListener
    ... 11 more
```

I have tried upgrading the 2.3 app to use the same hibernate as above and faced issues.

Attempting to use current non commented out hibernate:3.6.10.6 works on 2.3 apps but does not on 2.4. I get :

```
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.3" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"


| Error 2014-08-13 12:31:56,862 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'annotationHandlerAdapter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/support/UriComponentsContributor
Message: Error creating bean with name 'annotationHandlerAdapter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/support/UriComponentsContributor
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/support/UriComponentsContributor
->>  800 | defineClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    142 | defineClass in java.security.SecureClassLoader
|    449 | defineClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|     71 | access$100 in     ''
|    361 | run . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.method.support.UriComponentsContributor
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    800 | defineClass in     ''
|    142 | defineClass in java.security.SecureClassLoader
|    449 | defineClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|     71 | access$100 in     ''
|    361 | run . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/testmlist



    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"


| Error 2014-08-13 13:45:57,306 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    190 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/testmlist





    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"

hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = false
cache.use_query_cache = false
cache.provider_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}



| Error 2014-08-13 13:48:37,398 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.LRUMap
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/testmlist
```

Comment: I've done the sensible thing by defining above this version is for assets pre - use older versions.

Answer (score 5):

Pay atention to this section in DataSource.groovy (Grails 2.4.3):

```
    hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
        cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
//  cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this may have been the issue but to be honest I ended up upgrading it all which in short was probably the best thing for it.I had to return to all this for another app later which well lets not go there.. it remains on 2.3.7 :)